# Separate array by every six value and make MySql insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => A3C0101 
    [1] => Kun 
    [2] => Kame 
    [3] => 25.08. 14:00 
    [4] => NE 
    [5] => Sv 
    [6] => A3C0103 
    [7] => Popo 
    [8] => Ska 
    [9] => 24.08. 17:00 
    [10] => SO 
    [11] => 
    [12] => A3C0105 
    [13] => Muka 
    [14] => Stran 
    [15] => 24.08. 14:00 
    [16] => SO 
    [17] => 
    [18] => A3C0107 
    [19] => Lojoe 
    [20] => ©kvor 
    [21] => 25.08. 17:00 
    [22] => NE 
    [23] => 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ... 
    ...
    [467] => 
)
```

I need to separate this by every six value.
And I would like to make MySql insert like this:

```
    INSERT INTO `table` (`id` ,`one` ,`two`, `date` ,`den` ,`type`)
VALUES
  ('A3C0101', 'Kun', 'Kame', '25.08. 14:00', 'NE', 'Sv'),
  ('A3C0103', 'Popo', 'Ska', '24.08. 17:00', 'SO', ''),
  ('A3C0105', 'Muka', 'Stran', '24.08. 14:00', 'SO', ''),
  ('A3C0107', 'Lojoe', '©kvor', '25.08. 17:00', 'NE', ''),
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

Every six forms one insert.
I hope you understand.

Thanks for any advice!! :-)

Filip

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Thanks, Amal - I didn't ask the question but I had no idea that function existed. Very useful.

Comment: even simple loop with `$i=1` to `$i<=6` with reset every 6th time should do the job

Comment: I can't help wondering from where this array came, as it almost certainly should never have been flattened in this way.

Comment: @eggyal my thoughts exactly

Comment: @AmalMurali This is why I love answering questions, I get to read comments and find out about functions I never looked at :) +1

Answer (score 0):

This rather ugly loop should do the trick. As all your array elements seem to be strings, this will be easy. If not, you can stick another switch inside the inner loop to deal with particular elements that need date formatting or are numeric.

```
$i=0;
while($i<floor(count($yourArray)/6))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO `table` (`id` ,`one` ,`two`, `date` ,`den` ,`type`)
        VALUES (";
    for($j=0;$j<6;$j++)
    {
        $sql.="'".$yourArray[$i+$j]."', ";
    }
    $sql=rtrim($sql, ',');
    $sql.=");";
    // Run insert statement here.
    $i+=6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  php function `array_chunk()` for this. See Below:

```
 // take array of 6
 $input_array = array("1","2","3","4","5","6");
 // divide array in 2
 $divided_array = array_chunk($input_array, 2));

 foreach($divided_array as $value)
 {
     mysql_query("insert into `table_name` (col1,col2) values '".$value[0]."','".$value[1]."')");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Chunk the array and then implode it. The insert would fail if your chunked array has less than 6 elements [Reference array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
 //chunk the array in size of 6 where $arr is your array
 $arr_chunked = array_chunk($arr, 6);

    foreach($arr_chunked as $key=>$value)
    {
      if(is_array($value) && count($value)>0)
      {
        //prepare a string separated by comma for insert
          $insert_values = implode("','", $value) ;
          $insert_string = "'".$insert_values."'";
          //use the $insert_string to insert in database
      }
    }
```